# Angular.js compile partial view controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, razor

Hi I have a mvc application, with a home page and a partial view (`Info.cshtml`) in that homepage. When I add an angularjs controller to the `_Layout` (after: `var myModule = angular.module("myModule", ["kendo.directives"]);)` and have in `Info.cshtml`:

```
<div id="aaaa" ng-controller="test">{{msg}}</div>
<script>
    ///!!!!!!!!!!!!!IMPORTANT, do not remove!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    var $injector = angular.element($('#aaaa')).injector();
    var element = angular.element($('#aaaa'));
    $injector.invoke(function ($compile, $timeout) {
        var scope = element.scope();
        $compile(element)(scope);
        $timeout(function () {
            scope.$apply();
        });
    })
</script>
```

, everything is ok, but when I add the controller directly to the `Info.cshtml` it breaks `"Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'test' is not a function, got undefined"`:

```
<div id="aaaa" ng-controller="test">{{msg}}</div>
<script>
    myModule.controller("test", function ($scope, $http, $timeout) {
        alert('here');
        $scope.msg = 'dsadsadaddas';
    })

    ///!!!!!!!!!!!!!IMPORTANT, do not remove!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    var $injector = angular.element($('#aaaa')).injector();
    var element = angular.element($('#aaaa'));
    $injector.invoke(function ($compile, $timeout) {
        var scope = element.scope();
        $compile(element)(scope);
        $timeout(function () {
            scope.$apply();
        });
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Where do you init your module ? (myModule) ?

Comment: In Info.cshtml, the last code is the entire page. and the working part is initiated the same in _Layout

Comment: What happens if you place the `script` block before the `div` which references the `test` controller?

Comment: Nothing, it's the same thing.

Comment: hey did you ever figure this out, I got the same issue

Comment: Nope, :( still waiting for a guru here